# How to pass parameter using Ext.Ajax.request when method type is DELETE

Tags: rest, http, jersey, extjs4.1, http-delete

I am trying to send use `Ext.Ajax.request` method to delete some data on server. My request method looks as below :

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
      url: '/myserver/restful/service/delete',
      method: 'DELETE',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      params: {
        userId: 12345
      }
});
```

On my jersey server I have written which looks like as below :

```
@Path("/delete")
  @DELETE
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public Response deleteUser(final String userId) {
    System.out.println("user id = " + userId);
    return Response.ok().entity("success").build();
  }
```

This method prints out user id in following format :

`user id = userId=12345`

So my expected value for `userId` is `12345` but it is giving me `userId=12345`. As I am newbie to jersey thing, I am not able to decide what to do now.

Can anyone please tell what is going wrong?

Comment: I solved my problem by appending userId to url itself. Now my url part looks like '/myserver/restful/service/delete?userId=12345'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure about what's going wrong in Jersey, but... if you are trying to use DELETE with a request body you're on the wrong track anyway. Don't. The only relevant parameter for DELETE should be the request URI it's being applied to.

Answer (score 2):

@Julian is correct you really shouldn't have params with an HTTP DELETE verb.

Try this:

```
@Path("/delete/{userId}
```

Then inside of your method:

```
@PathParam("userId") String userId
```

And then when you call your service change your url to : `delete/(userId)` (without the parens) and remove the params.